# Vertical Align Text After Font Icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, vertical-alignment

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x blue"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-wifi fa-stack-1x white"></i>
    </span>
    <h4 class="blue">Free wifi</h4>
</div>
```

How can I display `h4` element on the right of the icon and vertically aligned? Should I float left the `span`?

Comment: You can simply use `display: flex` to parent element.

Comment: I've added it to div but the h4 is not vertically aligned.

Comment: It should, can u please put your code in some jsfiddle, might be some other css is conflicting with `display: flex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways would be to use `inline-block` display and *middle* align it - see demo below:

```css
.wrapper > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
.white {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="col-md-4 wrapper">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x blue"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-wifi fa-stack-1x white"></i>
    </span>
    <h4 class="blue">Free wifi</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: I like your solution, I suppose it's more compatible with IE.

Answer (score 1):

Use **CSS Flexbox**. Make a parent `<div>` that wraps icon and text into it (in my case its `icon-holder`) and make it a flexbox container using `display: flex`.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.icon-holder {
  display: flex; /* Flex Container */
  align-items: center; /* Vertically Align Content */
}

.blue {
  color: #33b5e5;
}

span {
  color: #fff;
}

h4 {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="icon-holder">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x blue"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-wifi fa-stack-1x white"></i>
    </span>
    <h4 class="blue">Free wifi</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex` and can do something like below :

- ```css
  .col-md-4 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .blue {
    color: blue
  }

  .white {
    color: white;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <div class="col-md-4 wrapper">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x blue"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-wifi fa-stack-1x white"></i>
      </span>
      <h4 class="blue">Free wifi</h4>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: I've added it but it's not vertically aligned...maybe bootstrap?

Comment: @Jumpa add `align-items: center;` to parent, this should do that trick.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I need to be IE8 compatible: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox